# How in Kotlin can I make function injectable and pass that function as function type to other functions?

Tags: kotlin, dagger

As in Kotlin function is considered data type also ,I’m wondering is it possible to make that function injectable and then can  I  pass that to other method.  What I mean is to make this function injectable
`fn: (data) -> Component` and then I will pass this to method

Comment: try with `typealias`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reference a function using `::` operator that will create a `KFunction1<data, Component>` which is considered as `(data) -> Component` or `data.() -> Component` in kotlin.

**Example:**

```kotlin
fun acceptLambda(block: (String) -> Unit) {
    block("Test")
}

// Create function having same argument and return type
// Both of them in same package won't work use either of these
fun String.t1() {
    println(this)
}
fun t2(s: String) {
    println(s)
}

// Call them, by passing the reference
test(String::t1) // Prints: Test
test(::t2)       // Prints: Test
```

Thing to be noted is that if you create an extension function as a member function in any class (just like `t1`) then it cannot be referenced, so I'll recommend using functions like t2 instead.

[Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type) is more info about how to reference constuctors, or memeber functions.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look [here.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)

> Kotlin functions are first-class, which means that they can be stored
>   in variables and data structures, passed as arguments to and returned
>   from other higher-order functions. You can operate with functions in
>   any way that is possible for other non-function values.

Example:

```kotlin
fun takeFunction(func: (Int) -> Component) {
  val component = func(1)
}

fun foo(data: Int) : Component = TODO()

fun main() {
  takeFunction({ if(it == 1) Component else error("wrong data") })
  takeFunction(::foo)
  takeFunction { foo(it) }
}
```